# Proving $f(x,y)$ is discontinuous at origin

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, partial-derivative

Show that the function defined by 
$$f(x,y) = \Bigg\{ \frac{x^3 + y^3 }{x-y}, \space when \space x \neq  y$$
and
$$f(x,y) = 0, \space when \space x = y$$

is discontinuous at the origin but possesses partial derivatives $f_x$ and $f_y$ at origin.

I am good with finding $f_x$ and $f_y$ at origin.

I am facing difficulty in proving discontinuous.

I tried to approach continuity as follows

$|f(x,y)-f(0,0)| = \bigg|\frac{x^3 + y^3 }{x-y} - 0 \bigg| \leq \frac{|x|^3 + |y|^3}{|x-y|}$

I couldn't proceed for here on wards, to prove discontinuity.

Please help me to prove discontinuity.

Comment: Try approaching the origin along a different line than the $x$ or $y$ axes, such as the line $y = 2x$.

Comment: I think it is continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $y=x-ax^3$. Then it holds that
$$\frac{x^3+y^3}{x-y}=\frac{2x^3+O(x^4)}{ax^3}.$$
The limit of this expression as $x$ approaches $0$ is $2/a$. Hence, the limit depends on how you approach the origin. The function is not continuous.

Comment: Is there any rule on how to take y value based on the definition of f(x,y). Please tell me, it would be helpful in solving other problems

Answer (score 0):

In fact this function maps every neighborhood of $(0,0)$ onto $\mathbb R.$ Whenever you see a polynomial denominator whose zero set approaches the origin, be on the lookout for this crazy behavior.